# Javascript what is the best way to filter objects based on a list of strings in an array?

Tags: javascript

I have the following array which has strings in it

```
const dict = ['original sound', 'الصوت الأصلي', 'оригинальный звук'];
```

Now I want to filter it based on the array using object filter

```
Object.filter = (obj, predicate) =>
    Object.keys(obj)
          .filter( key => predicate(obj[key]) )
          .reduce( (res, key) => (res[key] = obj[key], res), {} );

let filtered = Object.filter(audio, audio =>
  audio.audio.title !== dict
);
```

To be clear I don't want any music with the titles that match the dict array

Comment: `Object.filter` doesn't exist. What is `audio` in your example? Do you want to filter out objects whose titles are not in the array?

Comment: I have it just not included that part is fine. The audio has titles and some are 'original sound' I don't want to display them.

Comment: Define what you mean by "best way"?

Comment: Just a note: why not do both the filtering (`filter`) and the accumulating (`reduce`) in one go using just the `reduce`? In `reduce` check if a key passed the `predicate` then add it to the new object, otherwise ignore it, that way you don't need the `filter`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the array doesn't [include](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp) that element:

```
let filtered = Object.filter(audio, audio =>
   !dict.includes(audio.audio.title)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to filter an array of strings, based on another string array as dictionary, if so, try below

```
var filtered = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].filter(
  function(e) {
    return this.indexOf(e) < 0;
  },
  ['b', 'd']
);
```

becarefull of  string.**includes**(anotherString)  is NOT working on IE

Comment: Given that the code uses `const`, `let` and arrow functions, I doubt `includes` is a deal breaker.